# infobox moving away from circle

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I create the circle by calling on this function:

```
function buildCircle(radius, latitude, longitude){
  return new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    draggable: true,
    fillOpacity: 0,
    map: map,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    radius: radius
  });
}
```

and I call on display the labels by calling on this function:

```
function addLabelToCircle(labelText, width, latitude, longitude) { 
  var myOptions = new InfoBox({
    content: labelText,
    boxStyle: {
      position: "fixed",
      border: "none",
      marginLeft: width,
      fontSize: "10pt",
    },

    disableAutoPan: false,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-25, -5),
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    closeBoxURL: "",
    isHidden: false,
    pane: "overlayMouseTarget",
    enableEventPropagation: true
  });

  return myOptions;
}
```

This is how I pass in my params for these two functions:

```
  circle = buildCircle(185200, latitude, longitude);

  secondCircle = buildCircle(370400, latitude, longitude);

  thirdCircle = buildCircle(555600, latitude, longitude);

  ibLabel = addLabelToCircle("100", "90px", latitude, longitude);
  ibLabel.open(map);

  ibLabel2 = addLabelToCircle("200", "150px", latitude, longitude);
  ibLabel2.open(map);

  ibLabel3 = addLabelToCircle("300", "230px", latitude, longitude);
  ibLabel3.open(map);
```

The thing is as I zoom out I get the following display:
[image: Image 1]

When originally it was like this:
[image: Image 2]

How do I make it so that the box style stays the way it is (like Image 2) upon zooming in or out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a infobox to the right edge of a circle drawn via Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412224/add-a-infobox-to-the-right-edge-of-a-circle-drawn-via-google-maps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the geometry library to check the original position of the circle and then just added 90 degrees to it; so I can get the position of the circle wherever I click on the map and then I just added that position to the addition of the infobox labels. I used the following code to solve my problem:

```
ibLabel = window.MAP.addLabelToCircle("100", // This code was used in a google listener
window.MAP.labelPosition(circle));
ibLabel.open(map);

ibLabel2 = window.MAP.addLabelToCircle("200", 
window.MAP.labelPosition(secondCircle));
ibLabel2.open(map);

ibLabel3 = window.MAP.addLabelToCircle("300", 
window.MAP.labelPosition(thirdCircle));
ibLabel3.open(map); // this is the last line that was in the google listener

window.MAP.labelPosition = function(circle) {
   return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(circle.center, 
   circle.radius, +90);
}

window.MAP.addLabelToCircle = function(labelText, labelPosn) { 
var myOptions = new InfoBox({
content: labelText,
boxStyle: {
  border: "none",
  textAlign: "center",
  fontSize: "10pt",
  width: "80px",
},

disableAutoPan: false,
pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-25, -5),
position: new google.maps.LatLng(labelPosn.lat(), labelPosn.lng()),
closeBoxURL: "",
isHidden: false,
pane: "overlayMouseTarget",
enableEventPropagation: true
});

return myOptions;
}
```